# Using delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I've read up some of the basics on using delegates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I posted a question on SO and the following code was part of the answer.

Can this syntax be converted into syntax more like the MSDN article where a delegate is explicitly declared etc. or in certain circumstance is this the only way of coding it?

The reason I'm looking for an alternative way of coding it is that as a newbie to c# I find this line difficult to get my head around `this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate`

```
private void myTimer_Elapsed(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs){

        elapsedCounter++;
        elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);

        if (elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds < MaxTime)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                this.lblElapsedTime.Text = elapsedTime.ToString();

                if (elapsedCounter % 2 == 0)
                    this.lblValue.Text = EvenText;
                else
                    this.lblValue.Text = OddText;
            }));
        }
        else 
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            myTimer.Dispose();
            //myProcess.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thing is.. that *does* explicitly declare a delegate...? what sort of alternative syntax are you looking for?

Comment: woops! +1 for your diplomacy Marc. The syntax in the MSDN article seems to be more spelt out and easier for me to grasp what is happening. I assumed that `this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate` is doing quite a lot so I was hoping an alternative would split this out into more lines of code so I can see waht is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) is just a predefined delegate which takes no parameters and returns `void`:

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker()
```

You are perfectly free to create your own delegate instead, just like in the example you linked to:

```
private delegate void MyDelegate();
```

and replace `MethodInvoker` with `MyDelegate`.

In your code, an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) is created. The advantage of the anonymous method is that it could access local variables declared in `myTimer_Elapsed`. Since `elapsedTime` and `elapsedCounter` seem to be declared outside, you could replace this with an explicitly defined method as follows:

```
private void MyMethod() {
    this.lblElapsedTime.Text = elapsedTime.ToString();       

    if (elapsedCounter % 2 == 0)       
        this.lblValue.Text = EvenText;       
    else       
        this.lblValue.Text = OddText;       
}

private void myTimer_Elapsed(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs){       
    ...

    if (elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds < MaxTime)       
    {
        MyDelegate delegateToMyMethod = MyMethod;
        this.BeginInvoke(delegateToMyMethod);       
    }       
    else        
    {       
        ...
    }       
}
```